# expanding circle based on text inputed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to create a circle where if somebody key in anything in it, it will expand to fit whatever was keyed in. whenever a text is erased then the bubble gets smaller. I have a normal input text.

```
<input type="text"/>
```

and the circle css is :

```
input {border-radius: 50%;width: 50px;height: 50px;}
```

[edit]

Here is my jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/UxtJV/391/

the problem is that I need it to shrink when deleting the text

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/css/ and http://jsfiddle.net/jamwaffles/UxtJV/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the circle is your input and you're trying to expand it as the user is typing, this should give you a rough idea:

```
$('#circle').on('input', function () {
    var textLength = $(this).val().length;
    var textWidth = parseInt($('#circle').css('font-size'), 10) * textLength + 'px';
    $('#circle').css('width', textWidth);
    $('#circle').css('height', textWidth);
});
```

CSS:

```
input {
    border-radius: 50%;
    min-width: 50px;
    min-height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    text-align: center;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
    transition: all 0.5s;
}
```

It's using the font size property to calculate the character width, so it's inexact.

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/verashn/JaNMb/

Comment: I like it! please include the jsfiddle in your answer not in the comment section that way I can pick your answer as the best answer.

Comment: I edited the post and removed my (now redundant) comment.

Answer (score 2):

I was unsure whether you just wanted the width to expand when content was edited or height to expand in proportion too. I created the latter [here on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/M2unb/). It still needs some work to get the text centered vertically but it's a good start. In order to do this, I had to use a `div` with an attribute of `contenteditable` as inputs would not style correctly.